# How to Bind Parallax View within GridView DataTemplate?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp, parallax

I am trying to use a `ParallaxView` to make an image within the `GridViewItem` parallax as the `GridView` is scrolled. The intended effect is the same as the newsfeed in the Xbox UWP app on PC; images on the listview items there parallax as you scroll. This is shown visually in the following image:

[image: Annotated Layout Screenshot]

I am running into a databinding data context issue, however. All of the examples I have seen are to make the background of the entire `GridView` or `ListView` parallax. A working example of that is as follows (very similar to the XAML Controls Gallery Sample found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MSVH128X2ZT)):

```
    <Grid>
        <ParallaxView Name="GridViewParallaxView"
                      Source="{x:Bind MyGridView}"
                      VerticalShift="100">
            <!-- This is the background image that parallaxes. -->
            <Image></Image>
        </ParallaxView>

        <GridView Name="MyGridView">
            <!-- GridView Content Here... -->
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

The problem I am running into is when trying to place the `ParallaxView` INSIDE of the `DataTemplate` in the `ItemTemplate` in the `GridView`.

```
<GridView Name="MyGridView"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyDataList}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyDataType">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ParallaxView Name="GridViewParallaxView"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Source="{x:Bind MyGridView}"
                                  VerticalShift="100">
                        <!-- This is the image  ON EACH GRIDVIEW ITEM that parallaxes. -->
                        <Image Source="{x:Bind MySource}"></Image>
                    </ParallaxView>

                    <TextBlock Name="ItemTitleTextBlock"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Text="{x:Bind Title}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Note that some properties (like `MinWidth` and `Margin`) have been omitted for brevity.

The code behind (not totally relevant, but to add context to some of the bindings):

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataType> MyDataList { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataType
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ImageSource MySource { get; set; }
}
```

This does not work because placing the 'ParallaxView' inside of the 'DataTemplate' changes the 'DataContext'. `MyGridView` can no longer be bound to directly like that. So how do I bind it?

Also, I read that the `DataContext` property is inherited by children in the XAML tree. I need the `Image` databinding to be in the same context as the `DataTemplate`. Is there a way to just change the `DataContext` for the `ParallaxView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Binding, instead of x:Bind.

```
<ParallaxView Name="GridViewParallaxView"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Source="{Binding ElementName=MyGridView}"
                              VerticalShift="100">
                        <!-- This is the image  ON EACH GRIDVIEW ITEM that parallaxes. -->
                        <Image Source="{x:Bind MySource}"></Image>
</ParallaxView>
```

Comment: I implemented this, and it works as described! Thank you!